# Will two magnets with it's poles facing eachother repel?

Tags: magnetic-fields

I understand that N facing N will repel, but would it still repel if the magnetic field is slightly changed by this simple design of this classic magnet switch drawn in the photo?

[image: Two magnet switches]

[image: Single magnet switch]

Comment: It looks like you have built some. This puts you ahead of most people with questions. What did you find when you tried it?

Comment: This is actually an image I got online. I'd like to know if the poles would repel eachother with this simple design before I try to understand the science behind the more advanced magnet switch designs.

Comment: You should build one. You can find a dozen centimeter-scale permanent magnets at your hardware store for a couple of dollars. At the arts and crafts store they are slightly more expensive.

Comment: I'm going too! I must wait for a paycheck first but I'm seeking all knowledge I can before my trip to the store. I started with this simple design just to ask if they would still repel dispute the custom design. I'd love to know the science of this & especially of the more advanced magnet switch designs. Awesome little gadgets!